# how can I apply loop to multithreading in python

Tags: python, multithreading, loops

I just started learning about multithreading, and I have a question about applying loop.

As shown in code below I am trying to run multithreading until length of self.llist is longer than 10.

Code below works fine, but I'm not sure if that's efficient way to run in loop.

```
import threading

class aa:
    def __init__(self):
        self.llist = []

    def task1(self):
        self.llist.append('task1')

    def task2(self):
        self.llist.append('task2')

    def main(self):
        while len(self.llist) < 10:
            t1 = threading.Thread(target=self.task1, name='t1')
            t2 = threading.Thread(target=self.task2, name='t2')

            t1.start()
            t2.start()

            t1.join()
            t2.join()

aa().main()
```

Comment: that looks very much like a thread pool.

Comment: also if your code works, maybe it's not the proper site to ask a question. Better suited for codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

I tried with concurrent.futures and found out your execution times is less than ThreadPoolExecutor implementation. Here is the code:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from time import time


class aa:
    def __init__(self):
        self.llist = []

    def task(self, name):
        self.llist.append(name)

    def main(self):
        while len(self.llist) < 10:
            with ThreadPoolExecutor(2) as execute:
                thread_name = ['t1', 't2']
                execute.map(self.task, thread_name)
                print(self.llist)


start = time()
aa().main()
print(time()-start)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import threading

class aa:
    def __init__(self):
        self.llist = []

    def task1(self):
        self.llist.append('task1')

    def task2(self):
        self.llist.append('task2')

    def main(self):
        while len(self.llist) &lt; 10:
            t1 = threading.Thread(target=self.task1, name='t1')
            t2 = threading.Thread(target=self.task2, name='t2')

            t1.start()
            t2.start()

            t1.join()
            t2.join()

aa().main()
```